# Failure of the Vitali Covering Lemma for open coverings

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

**Definition:** Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a collection of non-degenerate closed intervals. If for every $\epsilon>0$ and for every $x\in E$ there exists $I\in\mathcal{F}$ with $x\in I$ and $l(I)<\epsilon$, then $\mathcal{F}$ is a Vitali covering of $E$.

**Vitali Covering Lemma:** Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ with $m^*(E)<\infty$ and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a Vitali covering of $E$. Then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a finite collection $\lbrace I_k\rbrace_{k=1}^n\subset\mathcal{F}$ such that $$m^*\left(E\setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^n I_k\right)<\epsilon$$

So, my goal is to show that if the condition of "closed intervals" is dropped and replaced with "general intervals" (defined by convexity in my case) then this Lemma fails.

That is, I need to show that there exists some $E\subset \mathbb{R}$, there exists a Vitali covering but with general intervals instead of closed ones, and there exists an $\epsilon_0>0$ such that whenever a finite collection of intervals is chosen from my bad Vitali covering $\lbrace I_k\rbrace_{k=1}^n$ we have

$$m^*\left(E\setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^n I_k\right)\geq\epsilon$$

I have tried this so far:

Let $E=[0,2]$. Let $\epsilon_0=1$. Let $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,2] =\lbrace r_i : i\in\mathbb{N}\rbrace$. Let $\mathcal{F}= \lbrace (r_i-2^i,r_i+2^i) : i\in\mathbb{N}\rbrace$. Then note that if $\lbrace I_k\rbrace_{k=1}^n\subset\mathcal{F}$ then $\sum I_k < 1$. So

$$m^*\left(E\setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^n I_k\right)=2-\sum I_k>2-1=1$$

I think it is painfully obvious that what I have isn't a covering. Even if you strung the intervals end to end - as spaced out as they could be while trying to cover, you would only get arbitrarily close to covering half of $[0,2]$. I've been looking in the wrong direction, could I have a hint?

Comment: Your attempt at a counter-example won't work if E is compact and F is an open cover of E, because then a finite subset of F will completely cover E.Perhaps there is something in the proof of the Vitali lemma where the properties of the members of F is crucial, which might give a hint .I'm just speculating,but it's often a good place to start.

Comment: What makes you think that the lemma is false for covers by non-closed intervals?

Comment: If $\cal I$ is a Vitali cover of $E$ by intervals, $\overline{\cal I} = \{ \overline I : I \in \cal I\}$ is too, except its intervals are closed.

Comment: @user254665 wow... Why didn't I see that? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich besides the problem being assigned to me? I don't have a sophisticated enough intuition to be able to tell you that I believe the claim before seeing the proof.

Comment: You were assigned the problem of showing it fails for open covers? Or was it "prove or disprove"? Or were you assigned the problem of explaining why that example was not a counterexample? If someone actually told you to prove it was false for open covers he shouldn't have...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot take an compact set $E=[0,2]$ as a counter-example since it is finite covering.

Here is a counter-example:

Let $E=(0,1)$ and $I_x$ is an open interval centered at $x$ with radius $r=\frac{\min\{x,1-x\}}{2}$. Then $\mathcal{F}=\{I_x\}_{x\in E}$ will be an open covering of $E$, but we cannot choose finite intervals such that $m^*\left(E\setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^n I_{x_k}\right)<\epsilon$.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on your counter-example? I didn't see why it must fail

Comment: Also, the intervals you constructed may not cover E in the sense of Vitali